# SQL AVG() confusion basic SQL

Tags: mysql

Part of my assignment says this
6. Display the student id and average score for each student.

This is what I came up with

```
SELECT student_id, AVG(score) FROM scores;
```

But it only brings up the average score of the  first student.
What do I need to change?

Comment: You're missing a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You should add GROUP_BY to perform aggregated function like `AVG()`. `SELECT student_id, AVG(score) FROM scores GROUP BY student_id`;

Comment: "this 6" - what does that mean?

Comment: Thanks! there is suppose to be a comma after 'this' haha

Comment: If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows. - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You need a groupby operator.

```
SELECT student_id, AVG(score) FROM (table_name) GROUPBY student_id
```

Maybe, the table like this,

```
|class_id|class_name|student_id|student_name|score|
```

You have to decribe your table in detail. Anyway, I think `GROUPBY` is all you need in this question.

Comment: `GROUPBY` -> `GROUP BY` and don't put `table_name` in `()` (confusing).

Comment: you are right, my mistake. I don't know his table name, so I put it here.Maybe it's confusing.

Comment: the name is `scores` in the question. But generally abstract table_name can be inteprated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query with GROUP BY

```
SELECT student_id, AVG(score) FROM scores GROUP BY student_id
```